# Same process in different data frames with R

Tags: r, function, loops

I want to know if is possible to do the same process en different data frames in R, for example:
I had 5 different data frames and I want to do in each one the next process:

1. Converting a column as a row names

> rownames(x1) <- x1$Var1

2. Transposing de data frame

> x1.t <- as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(x1)))

3. Calculating a correlation:

> x1.corr <- cor(x1.t, method = "spearman")

I don't want to have a lot of code, and I think it could be done with functions and loops, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Thanks very much, any advice or material will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `lapply` function. Supose you have 5 data frames *df1*, *df2*, *df3*, *df4* and *df5*, try this:

```
# Create a list of df's
df_list <- list(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5)

# Create a fuction with the process you want
process <- function(x1){
      rownames(x1) <- x1$Var1
      x1.t <- as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(x1)))
      x1.corr <- cor(x1.t, method = "spearman")
      return(x1.corr)
}

# Apply lapply function
lapply(df_list,process)
```

Answer (score 1):

To invoke the function you can use `result <- myfun(my_data_frame)`. Results will be in a list from which you can select the elements using `result[[1]]` or `result[[2]]`.

```
myfun <- function(x1) {
    result.list <- list()
    rownames(x1) <- x1$Var1
    result.list[[1]] <- as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(x1)))
    names(result.list)[1] <- "x1.t"
    result.list[[2]] <- cor(x1.t, method = "spearman")
    names(result.list)[2] <- "x1.corr"
    result.list
}
```